# Bootstrap cutting out words

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Am starting out on learning bootstrap 4 on my own and am having trouble as to why bootstrap is only showing part of my footer (i.e i can only see the "privacy policy" ) on my browser. I even tried creating a  tag at the top but cant get it to display. The menu section is okay. Below is my HTML from my index file. I have no content yet on my CSS file. Any suggestion is highly welcomed. Also below is an image how it appears;

[Bootstrap clipping words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzpkO.png)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    <title>Gamma</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand em-text" href="index.html">Gamma</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample09" aria-controls="#navbarsExample09" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toogle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample09">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html" class="nav- 
            link">Home</a</li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
            <p>Copyright &copy;2017, All Rights Reserved</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than 12 units for your columns.
Looks like you're missing a `row` around the Copyright div.

Should it look like this?

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        <p>Copyright &copy;2017, All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

See the reference here for more details: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: a "row" was already present in the code The "fixed top" nav bar was the issue, adding some top-margin fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a fixed navbar, which makes it overlap your footer. Give the content you don't want to be overlapped by the navbar a top margin.

Comment: Wow Thanks, that was so easy didn't realize the "fixed top" was the problem. Thanks.